# LLDB: print variables passed to function each time it's called?

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, function, lldb

There's an undocumented (private) framework for OS X called MobileDevice. It's used to get data from iOS devices. I'm in the process of writing an application that uses it and I want to be able to extract the number of charge cycles on the iOS device's battery. The function for doing this in MobileDevice is called AMDeviceCopyValue(). It takes 3 arguments: the address of the device (just an integer), the domain of the value you'd like to copy (a C string), and the key of the value you'd like to copy (another C string.)

Since this framework isn't documented, it's difficult to find what strings you need to use. Some of them have been posted online, but not the one for counting charge cycles. Another program I found online already does this, iCopyBot: http://www.icopybot.com/blog/check-ipad-iphone-battery-charge-cycle-count-without-jailbreaking.htm

I'd like to launch iCopyBot in LLDB, and then have LLDB print out the domain and key arguments that iCopyBot passes to AMDeviceCopyValue() each time it's called. The framework is sensitive about timing, so I can't have it halting mid-execution - it needs to just print the arguments that were passed and keep going.

Can anyone show me what I have to do? I've already managed to launch iCopyBot in LLDB and I have set a breakpoint each time that function is called, but the command "frame variable" doesn't print out anything for me (the documentation for LLDB that I got off of Apple's website suggests that it should print the arguments that were passed in... it didn't work for me.)

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on `AMDeviceCopyValue` and print the arguments while the program is the paused state.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I have managed to get it to pause when the function is called, but "frame variable" doesn't print out anything for me. And since this is a C function we're talking about, I don't think the variable names used on the source code would stick around in the compiled code, would they?

Comment: only if the module which the function in question resides in has been compiled with debugging symbols.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Okay so... lets assume they no longer have names. How do I print out their values? They're still C-strings, and based on the arguments I've seen so far that work, I assume I'll be able to make something out of them (the domain arguments I've seen so far are always in the form `com.apple.something` and the key arguments are always in camel case English, like BatteryCharge. I assume the other ones will be similar.)

Comment: Then it's a bit more complicated, basically you'll need to consult the ABI docs of your platform, and figure out where each argument is stored (for example, on x64, the first one goes into RDI). Then, armed with that information, you can use the debugger to e. g. `print $rdi` in order to get the value in that register.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Thanks for the help so far. I found that `register read` will print out a list of all of the registers and that `po <register>` will print out any Obj-C or CoreFoundation object descriptions. I think I have just one last question before I'm done: how do I provide a list of breakpoint commands and automatically continue after those commands run?

Comment: You're welcome. [This](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) says that you can just `breakpoint command add 1`, then print the variables and `continue`.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I tried that, but it didn't work for me. It would print out all of the variables, then say it was continuing, and then immediately it would break with `EXC_BREAKPOINT` and it wouldn't resume until I typed continue.

Comment: Obviously, you need to add `continue` to the batch of commands which are to be executed automatically.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Yes, and I just said that I did that. The debugger even printed out a message saying that it was continuing, but then it halted immediately after with EXC_BREAKPOINT. Since that was the only breakpoint I had set, it seems to me that it shouldn't have stopped there unless there's some bug in LLDB.

Comment: Seems strange. What if you end it with *two* `continue` commands (as a temporary, hackish workaround)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To surmise what was learned from my discussion in the comments of the question with H2CO3:

You can load any program you want in LLDB by typing the following command:

```
lldb <path to application executable>
```

To set a breakpoint on a function, type in the following command after lldb has started:

```
breakpoint set -b <name of function>
```

To actually start the program in lldb, type in the following once it's loaded and has the breakpoints you want:

```
run
```

To view the variables at the breakpoint, even without the debugger symbols (IE, because this isn't a program that you have the source to) type in:

```
register read
```

If anything in the list looks like it has a CoreFoundation or Obj-C object, type the following:

```
po <register of object>
```

And finally, if you think there's a C string being pointed to by one of the variables, you can use this:

```
p (char*)<register of string>
```

There's a lot more you can do with lldb than I covered here. Just type `help` from the lldb prompt to see more of what it can do. This covers everything I wanted to know when I first posted this question yesterday, though.